# MYSQL Deleting Duplicate Rows per id, title within past 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, duplicates, rows

I currently have it deleting duplicates but the process takes too long so I am trying to slim it and rather have it check periodically for new duplicates via possibly a cron job later or turn it into a php script.  ID is primary key.  Here is what I have so far.

This checks for duplicates and works well.

```
SELECT title, COUNT(title) 
FROM `ttrss_entries` 
WHERE date(date_entered) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE 
GROUP BY title 
HAVING COUNT(title) > 1
```

The delete that takes out the duplicates but takes about 30 minutes to complete. Was hoping I can add the date time to check it for past 10 minutes every 5 minutes or so.

```
DELETE n1 
FROM `ttrss_entries` n1, `ttrss_entries` n2 
WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.title= n2.title


$usth = $pdo->prepare(
                    "INSERT INTO ttrss_entries
                        (title,
                        guid,
                        link,
                        updated,
                        content,
                        content_hash,
                        no_orig_date,
                        date_updated,
                        date_entered,
                        comments,
                        num_comments,
                        plugin_data,
                        lang,
                        author)
                    VALUES
                        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                        false,
                        NOW(),
                        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

                    $usth->execute([$entry_title,
                        $entry_guid_hashed,
                        $entry_link,
                        $entry_timestamp_fmt,
                        "$entry_content",
                        $entry_current_hash,
                        $date_feed_processed,
                        $entry_comments,
                        (int)$num_comments,
                        $entry_plugin_data,
                        "$entry_language",
                        "$entry_author"]);
```

Comment: A cron job? But surely you're only ever going to run this once?

Comment: once per day but then again it does add alot of duplicates so I would either need to find a way from duplicates being created on insert so far has failed or run this as a cronjob / script multiple times within the hour.

Comment: Yes. Find a way to prevent duplicates from being created

Answer (score 0):

if cron is not possible with this then yea once a day would suffice.  But the load time is just too long for the delete process.

Answer (score 0):

Why, exactly, are you chasing duplicates for deletion instead of having a unique constraint on tress.title that prevents duplicates from being inserted in the first place?

Or you could make your code use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Or you can write a before-insert trigger to do this.

Chasing duplicates seems like a far worse solution than preventing them.

Comment: Because its a pre-made script named Tiny Tiny RSS and I believe it already has that in the code.  Unfortunately its not successful.

Comment: Does the code choke on a unique constraint? If so a before-insert trigger should allow you to silently discard the duplicate.

Comment: I found that it check only for duplicate hash not duplicate title or content.  So I am not sure if I can use that method I will post the insert code above.

Comment: You can define a unique constraint any way you like, the question is whether the code will break horribly of the database returns an error when the code tries to insert a record that would result in a unique constraint violation.

Comment: ok I received this Error Message E_USER_NOTICE (1024) SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Comment: Right, so the code doesn't handle it gracefully. You'll need to write a trigger to silently discard duplicates.